# Rewrite not working for mysite/index

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following .htaccess file in mysite/folder:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

It's working for mysite/folder/anything, except for mysite/folder/index. The error given is "The requested URL /mysite/folder/index/ was not found on this server."

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take out 2nd rewrite rule from your code:

```
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

 RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: These type of comments never help. For which URL it didn't work? Are there more rules? What is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: Like I explain in the question: .htaccess is at mysite/folder/. There are no more rules. The only one URL that didn't work is "mysite/folder/index". Index is literaly "index".